# Install Linux (BackBox/Ubuntu) beside Mac OSX

Tags: linux, macos, operating-systems

I have a MacBook Pro late 2008, 120 GB SSD & 250 GB instead of the CD-Drive. Now there's Mac OSX on both, but I want to install Linux Ubuntu on the HDD. Now there is the problem: "What Bootloader, etc. do I have to use, that also OSX is able to boot again?"

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DualBoot/MacOSX might be helpful for DualBooting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a thing one needs to understand before doing this:

> The Mac platform is unique in that all boot processes occur using EFI
> in conjunction with GPT. For this reason, it's a platform where GRUB
> is not installed to the MBR--because the Mac doesn't use MBR! Apple
> was ahead of the curve by using EFI and GPT, at the expense of
> compatibility with many operating systems using the legacy (but
> easier) bootloading methods.
>
> [Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DualBoot/MacOSX)

Now that you understand why Macs are different from most other platforms in this regard (and why it might be slightly more difficult to achieve multi-boot because of this), you can follow the steps [over here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation) to achieve "Dual Boot". The steps you will follow are:

1. Installing [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/doc/c1s1_install.html)
2. Using Bootcamp or Disk Utility to create a partition at the end of the disc
3. Booting from the [Ubuntu CD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and installing the system
4. Having rEFIt re-sync your partitions

Comment: thank you, i totally forgot that post, i'm running on ubuntu now ;D